# redirect ALL output from shell to a command to act as filter

Tags: linux, bash, grep, sed

How to redirect all std-output from bash to a command like 'grep' or 'sed' to filter the output and then write it to a file?

This is what I want in principle: `exec > >(cat | cat >>/tmp/myoutput.txt)`.
The last command works as expected.
But if I replace the first `cat` with `grep -v 'foo'` or with `sed 's/foo/bar/g'` no data is written into file.

**How to get the above example to work with grep or sed?**

*Background:*
I would like to filter errormessages from .xsession-errors.
`sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' .xsession-errors`
is not working because sed replaces the file .xsession-errors and future output from programms is not visible.
So one option to achieve would be to replace a line in /etc/X11/Xsession with code that filters messages.

**More info here:**

- I used `cat` 2 times to show that pipes are working like expected in
  subshell and to route everyting into a file. The `cat` is of course
  not needed in final version.
- I had enough output to fill buffers, I think, because I did several
  times `ls /usr/` to fill buffers.)
- `exec | sed ...` is not working

Comment: Why create a sub-process and `cat` std-in to another `cat`? Have you tried `exec | sed ... >> file`?

Comment: Perhaps you just don't have enough output yet to fill a buffer?

Comment: (1) It might help if you showed the actual commands you've used, rather than saying "I want to do something like `cat | cat` except with some other command in place of `cat`."  (2) I tried what I *think* you tried, and it worked the way you wanted.  (3) Can you do `bash | sed …` rather than starting bash and then redirecting its output?

Comment: Read the question several times still can't understand it...anyway, did you try the [tee](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tee-invocation.html#tee-invocation)?

Answer (score 0):

**Example:**

1. open a bash
2. call the command `exec > >(cat | cat >>/tmp/myoutput.txt)`
3. call another command eg. `ls -R /usr'
4. end bash with `exit`
5. have a look into file /tmp/myoutput.txt, you will see the output of the `ls`command
6. if you exchange the command from step with this `exec > >(sed 's/usr/--HEREAMI--/g' >/tmp/myoutput2.txt)`

This is working .. at the end 
So it seems, it is indeed a problem with filling buffers. Several `ls /usr` are not enough, but `ls -R /usr`fills the buffer. So now I need to figure out howto prevent buffering.

(Thanks for commenting and for requesting an example, this brought the solution.)